Javascript function to play songs not working Django app
i'm making a music streaming website and i have this js function that plays the songs on a single player onclick. the songs are playing correctly but when i click on them the player takes always the song name, the song artist and the song image of the first song, also if i click on the others. how can i fix that?
This is the js function:
function playSong(element){
        var songUrl = element.getAttribute('data-song-url');
        var audioPlayer = document.getElementById('audioPlayer');
        var audioSource = document.getElementById('audioSource');
        audioSource.src = songUrl;
        audioPlayer.load();
        audioPlayer.play();
        var songId = element.id;
        var newImage = document.getElementById("A_" + songId).src;
        var newSongName = document.getElementById("B_" + songId).textContent;
        var newArtistName = document.getElementById("C_" + songId).textContent;
        console.log(newSongName) //always displaying the things of the first song
        console.log(newImage)
        console.log(newArtistName)
        
        document.getElementById("audio-img").src = newImage;
        document.getElementById("audio-song").textContent = newSongName;
        document.getElementById("audio-artist").textContent = newArtistName;
    }

and this is the HTML code:
{% for i in songs %}
            <div class="carousel-cell">
                <section class="main_song">
                    <div class="song-card">
                        <div class="containera">
                            <img src="{{i.image}}" id="A_{{i.id}}" alt="song cover">
                            <div class="overlaya"></div>
                            <div>
                                <a class="play-btn" data-song-url="{{i.song.url}}" id="{{i.id}}" onclick="playSong(this)"><i class="fas fa-play-circle fa-2x"></i></a>
                                {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                                    <div class="add-playlist-btn">
                                        <a id="W_{{i.song_id}}" title="Add to Playlist" onclick="showDiv(this)"><i class="fas fa-ellipsis-h"></i></a>
                                    </div>
                                {% endif %}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <p class="songName" id="B_{{i.id}}">{{i.name}}</p>
                        <p class="artistName" id="C_{{i.id}}">{{i.artist}}</p>
                    </div>
                </section>
            </div>
  {% endfor %}


Have you verified what the generated HTML looks like? Do the element IDs look like you expected them to?

yes, because the song is correctly playing when i click on the play button

The song playing part works based on the data-song-url attribute of the element you are accessing directly via this. That has little to do with the rest. The problem appears to be with those IDs, that you tried to append this {{i.id}} suffix to.

@CBroe you're right. i was using the ids not correctly. Thank you very much!!!
